# Is the UUID command missing in 10.8.2?

Tags: macos, uuid

I just noticed that the uuid command is no longer working on my MacBook. One possibility is that it was removed when I upgraded to Mountain Lion. The man page is still available.

```
man uuid
```

Does anybody else have this problem with 10.8.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you probably are looking for is `uuidgen`.

`man uuid` shows the manpage for the UUID library (uuid.h).